# How to select a circle, drag and drop it to another location within a windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a windows form application. When I click anywhere on the form a small circle is drawn using the [Graphics.DrawEllipse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt06kxfd.aspx) method. I currently store the center point of the circle in a list to check if the point I clicked lies within the circle. How do I select a circle, drag and drop it to another location within the form?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Do you require the circle to move with the pointer to the new location or just for it to appear once you unclick the mouse at the new location?

Comment: @CathalMF: Thank you for your reply. I would like the circle to appear after I unclick the mouse at the new location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did not provide enough details about your current approach, I created a full example from scratch. This example allows creation of circles of various sizes by clicking and dragging, and also drag & drop operations over created circles.

Basically, as you already said, you need to store the coordinates of created circles. I have expanded that into a custom class "MyCircle" which contains the coordinates and radius of the circle.

The draw function loops through these objects and draws each one appropriately.

The part you were having difficulty with is regarding the drag & drop operation over already created objects.

First, I created a variable to hold the selected circle
I also wanted to enable the extra feature to enable you to "grab" the circle at any point, you don't always drag it from the center, so I added a point to track the offset of the click from the circle center, which will help us to position the circle after dragging.

```
private MyCircle activeCircle;
private Point dragOffset;
```

I then did a check in the mouse down event, to see if the user clicked on any of the circles, if so, I store a reference to the clicked circle in the activeCircle variable and I calculate the dragOffset by deducting the circle's center position (x and y) from the current mouse pointer position.

like this:

```
activeCircle = CheckIfCircleClicked(e.Location);
dragOffset = new Point(activeCircle.Point.X - e.Location.X, activeCircle.Point.Y - e.Location.Y);
```

On mouse move and mouse up events, you can check if the activeCircle reference is not null, and update the circle's position accordingly.

something like this:

```
activeCircle.Point = new Point(e.Location.X + dragOffset.X, e.Location.Y + dragOffset.Y);
```

and that is basically it.

Be sure to check out the full project that I linked to, as it will show you how to differentiate between create and drag operations, dynamically adjust the size of the circle while drawing it, and will generally show you how the whole solution works.

This code assumes you have a form and on it a picturebox called "pictureBox1".
You would also have to hook up the mouse down, move and up events manually to the picturebox control.

```
namespace DragAndDropCircles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<MyCircle> myCircles = new List<MyCircle>();
        private MyCircle activeCircle;
        private bool drawing = false;
        private bool dragging = false;
        private Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue));
        private Point dragOffset;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

            drawing = false;
            dragging = false;

            activeCircle = CheckIfCircleClicked(e.Location);
            if (activeCircle == null)
            {
                activeCircle = new MyCircle(e.Location, 0);
                drawing = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dragging = true;
                dragOffset = new Point(activeCircle.Point.X - e.Location.X, activeCircle.Point.Y - e.Location.Y);
            }
        }

        private MyCircle CheckIfCircleClicked(Point point)
        {
            return
                myCircles.FirstOrDefault(
                    circle =>
                        Math.Abs(circle.Point.X - point.X) < circle.Radius &&
                        Math.Abs(circle.Point.Y - point.Y) < circle.Radius);
        }


        public class MyCircle
        {
            public Point Point { get; set; }
            public double Radius { get; set; }

            public MyCircle(Point point, Double radius)
            {
                Point = point;
                Radius = radius;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drawing)
            {
                activeCircle.Radius = Math.Max(Math.Abs(e.Location.X - activeCircle.Point.X),
                    Math.Abs(e.Location.Y - activeCircle.Point.Y));
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
            else if (dragging)
            {
                activeCircle.Point = new Point(e.Location.X + dragOffset.X, e.Location.Y + dragOffset.Y);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
                return;

            if (activeCircle == null)
                return;

            if (dragging)
            {
                activeCircle.Point = new Point(e.Location.X + dragOffset.X, e.Location.Y + dragOffset.Y);
            }
            else if (drawing)
            {
                activeCircle.Radius = Math.Max(Math.Abs(e.Location.X - activeCircle.Point.X),
                    Math.Abs(e.Location.Y - activeCircle.Point.Y));
                myCircles.Add(activeCircle);
            }
            dragging = false;
            drawing = false;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.Clear(Color.White);

            foreach (var circle in myCircles.Where(c=>c!= activeCircle))
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(pen, (float) (circle.Point.X - circle.Radius), (float) (circle.Point.Y - circle.Radius),
                    (float) (circle.Radius*2),
                    (float) (circle.Radius*2));
            }

            if (activeCircle != null)
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(pen, (float) (activeCircle.Point.X - activeCircle.Radius),
                    (float) (activeCircle.Point.Y - activeCircle.Radius), (float) (activeCircle.Radius*2),
                    (float) (activeCircle.Radius*2));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the project; it works good. I recommend you to add the answer here itself. It is not much code. Because,your dropbox project could go invalid someday. Btw +1 :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I followed your advice and posted the complete code. Thanks.

Comment: @irreal I appreciate the effort. Thanks. I've updated your post to remove insignificant code.

Answer (score 5):

Since you didn't provide code, we couldn't fix your code. Instead, I provide a simple working of how you could to draw a circle and move it.

```
private readonly List<Circle> circles = new List<Circle>();
private Circle selectedCircle = null;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Circle hitCircle = circles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Bounds.Contains(e.Location));
    if (hitCircle == null)
    {
        circles.Add(new Circle { Bounds = new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(50, 50)) });
        this.Invalidate();
        selectedCircle = null;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedCircle = hitCircle;
    }

    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (selectedCircle != null && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        selectedCircle.Move(e.Location);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var circle in circles)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, circle.Bounds);
    }

    base.OnPaint(e);
}

public class Circle
{
    public Rectangle Bounds { get; set; }

    public void Move(Point currentMousePoint)
    {
        Bounds = new Rectangle(currentMousePoint, Bounds.Size);
    }
}
```

This snippet should get you an idea. I'm sure you can modify the code to make the changes to meet your requirements.

This code will create new circle if you click on the Form if there is no circle underneath, if there exist a circle already, it will select it. Moving the mouse will actually move the circle.

Note: This code should be placed in a in a derived class of `Control`. `base` keyword refers to the `Control` or `Form` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to just get the current cursors position using:

```
Cursor.Position
```

Then just delete the circle and redraw it using the new coordinates supplied by the Cursor.Position.
Make sure to check that the new position is within the bounds of the form.